# Insert Null value into TSQL database

Tags: c#, database, dbnull

I am a little bit stucked even I have read qustions about null and databases. I am trying to figure out how can I send NULL to the database form C#. Method singature is

```
MyMethod(string category, int? calories, int vegetarianFriendlyMeal);
```

when called with not null int it is ok but when I pass **null** it says.

> SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set type.

Would you please tell me how to allow passing a null to the database and and explicitly set type in the code below? Thank you.

```
            command.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = category;
            command.Parameters.Add("@veg", SqlDbType.Int).Value = vegetarianFriendlyMeal;
            if (calories == null)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@calories", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@calories", SqlDbType.Int).Value = calories;
            }
```

I have also tried

```
SqlParameter cal = new SqlParameter("@calories", calories == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : calories);
command.Parameters.Add(cal);
```

with the same result.

Comment: Using `.Value = calories ?? (object)DBNull.Value;` should work just fine. The only difference is the value, so why do you create the parameter in two different ways?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the whole code? I don't see any problems from the first glance. Are there other parameters in the query?

Comment: @Luaan Thank you this works as well and saves the that if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@calories", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple here. In case 1, .NET using `AddWithValue` can't infer associated type of `DBNull.Value`. The solution of case 1 is :

```
command.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = category;
command.Parameters.Add("@veg", SqlDbType.Int).Value = vegetarianFriendlyMeal;
if (calories == null)
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@calories", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (object)DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@calories", SqlDbType.Int).Value = calories;
}
```

In case 2, you don't give a type at all. The solution would be:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = category;
command.Parameters.Add("@veg", SqlDbType.Int).Value = vegetarianFriendlyMeal;
SqlParameter cal = new SqlParameter("@calories", calories == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : calories);
cal.DbType = SqlDbType.Int;
command.Parameters.Add(cal);
```

But if you want to make it clean you can do something like that:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = category;
command.Parameters.Add("@veg", SqlDbType.Int).Value = vegetarianFriendlyMeal;
command.Parameters.Add("@calories", SqlDbType.Int).Value = calories ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

EDIT : Don't use `AddWithValue`. It's risky to let .NET fill holes for you.

Comment: Thank you as well. I usually go with .Add but here I was stuck and hoped that .AddWithValue will solve this for me.